# Flex 3 or 4. To have TabNavigator with the Button on the Bottom

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, tabnavigator

Is it possible to place the Tabs on the bottom of a TabNavigator?

Currently, I want to see if Flex4 can create tabs for me positioned on the bottom.

Currently I can use library://ns.tink.ws/flex/mx for his positionedTabNavigator and yet it looks wonky, when I apply rounded corners on the tab, it rounds the wrong end.

Answer (score 1):

There is no TabNavigator in Flex 4 (at least not a Spark component), you have to roll your own out of a TabBar and a ViewStack. So the good news is, you can put the TabBar anywhere you want.

Here's an example: http://devgirl.wordpress.com/2009/11/16/tabbed-navigation-in-flex-4/

Comment: Thanks Dmitri!
I applied the following example to render dynamically the number of Tabs I have from a server, though how can I place it on the bottom. By default it's the upper left, rounded corners upwards.

Nowhere is it that I can find the placement property of the Spark TabBar?